# AJAX - prompt to save before the download begin

Tags: javascript, ajax

This is an ajax call that prompts the user to save the response as a file:

```
$http.get("api.php",{responseType:'arraybuffer'}).then(function(response){
    var blob = new Blob([response.data], {type: "application/pdf"});
    saveAs(blob, filename);
});
```

(`saveAs` is from [FileSaver.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/))

The problem is that the prompt dialog shows only after the response is fully loaded. If the response is large, the user has to wait for a while before seeing the prompt dialog. And he/she can't cancel the download.

Usually when the browser downloads a file from a direct link, it prompts to save before the download begins.

Is it possible to do the same with AJAX?

Comment: What component is $http? Is from angular or some other framework?

Comment: Yes it's using AngularJs as an example, but AngularJs is irrelevant to the question.

Comment: Don't understand why you need to do it with ajax...? Adding `content-disposition` outweighs FileSaver.js by a lot! It's best to use it when ever possible. FileSaver.js is good if you have stuff on the client-side

Comment: I have a very long string data to send along with the GET request. It'll just make the URL very ugly.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing to do would be to wrap the whole thing in an `if (confirm('Are you sure you want to save?'))`.

Answer (score 0):

use anchor element with download option and link with query params to your api like `<a href="api.php?some=params" download="yourfile.pdf">your file</a>`